# How to automatically increment Django IntegerField

Tags: python, django, methods, model, auto-increment

I have a field in my model

```
Step=models.IntegerField()
```

I call it normally in the template with the following:

```
{{user.step}}
```

Now I want this field to automatically increase after every year

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Is it based on some timestamp? like a birth date?

In this case you have few option:

1. Make it a property and recalculate it before sending data to template

   ```
   from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

   @property
   def step(self):
       return relativedelta(datetime.now(), self.timestamp).years
   ```
2. Make cronjob that will update step field every day using method above

Comment: So I have to install cronjob library right? I was thinking of a way to do it without any third party library

Comment: Cron is build into Linux. You should be able to run django command with something like "* * * * * python /path/to/project/manage.py management_command"